# USB CDC on Windows 8 RT

Tags: c#, .net, windows-8, cdc

Can a Windows Store Application communicate with a USB-connected device through a virtual COM Port?

Does the framework for such apps contain the SerialPort class?

If not, in what other way can I create a connection between a device and an App?

All this assuming that Classic Desktop is unavailable.

Comment: Looks like the answer [is no](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wdk/thread/b2924065-1627-400d-9b81-6990c53e1652/)

Comment: Unfortunate. Is there another way to communicate with a USB connected device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't the first to ask. But let me be the first to answer: http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2012/05/metro-answers-can-i-use-serial-port.html

The short answer is no. With this exception: the device is on USB (with a dongle) with a modern driver exposing IOCTLS device information – this gives Windows Store Apps device access.